# Woocommerce - Displaying only the parent category under the product title

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm running this script to show the product category under the product titles on my website:

```
function wpa89819_wc_single_product(){

    $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );

    if ( $product_cats && ! is_wp_error ( $product_cats ) ){

        $single_cat = array_shift( $product_cats ); ?>

        <h6 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title"><?php echo $single_cat->name; ?></h6>

<?php }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'wpa89819_wc_single_product', 2 );
```

It's working, however not how I want it to. I would like to only show the parent category for every product. At the moment it seems to pick the lowest child category.

I'm just starting to learn php, so any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your parent categories are top level categories - i.e., without parents of their own - you could use the following code safely:

```
function wpa89819_wc_single_product() {

    $product_cats = wp_get_post_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_cat' );

    if ( ! is_wp_error ( $product_cats ) ) {  //probably not necessary, but I see you're begin extra-careful...

        foreach( $product_cats as $cat ) {

            if ( 0 === $cat->parent ) { // top-level cat has "0" as parent ?>

                <h6 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></h6>

            <?php 

                break;

            }

        }

    }

}

add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'wpa89819_wc_single_product', 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, initially it didn't do the trick, it did make the h6 class, but didn't show the text. After double checking the top level categories, I noticed the code still states 'single_cat' in the h6 class line, which should be changed to just cat, as that's what you used for the if statement. After changing that, its working great. Thank you!

Comment: Oops... fixed it. That's what you get for posting un-tested code! Glad it helped.

Comment: I never asked why you gave the action such a low priority (2). 10 is default. Probably won't make a difference, but, unless you have a reason, maybe better not to do something peculiar... Just a thought.

Comment: also added a break for after finding the one needed result